# Find index value of where a appears as substring in b | Swift

Tags: swift

I am trying to write a function when passed two integers the function returns the left most position when a appears in b, this is about the decimal representation of where a appears in b counting from 0, so 66 appears at position 4 in 22331166.

So I convert both integers two strings, then check in b constains a, however how can I then find the left most position a appears in b ?

```
public func solution(_ A : Int, _ B : Int) -> Int {

let a = String(A)
let b = String(B)


if b.contains(a) {


} else {
    return 0
}

return 1
}

solution(33, 88553344)
```

The function should return 3, as 88 should be 1, 55 is 2 and 33 is 3.

Comment: If you are looking for an index the "33" position in "88553344" would be 5 not 3

Comment: What is the result you expect?

Comment: @LeoDabus I think he means 88 - 1, 55 - 2, 33 - 3, 44 -4

Comment: So the position depends on the length of A? This question is totally unclear. What if A is equal to 3?

Answer (score 0):

converted the string b into the character array and iterating and comparing it with the string a.

```
  public func solution(_ A : Int, _ B : Int) -> Int {

        let a = String(A)
        let b = String(B)


        if b.contains(a) {
        let characters = Array(b)

        for i in 0..< characters.count-1{
        let cont = "\(characters[i])+\(characters[i+1])"
        if cont == a{
        print("the index is \(i)")

        return i
        } 
         return 0   
        } else {
            return 0
        }

        }
```

Comment: You should ***really* tidy up that indenting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the way you can achieve it:

```
public func solution(_ A : Int, _ B : Int) -> Int {

    let a = String(A)
    let b = String(B)

    if b.contains(a) {

        let range = b.range(of: "\(a.first!)")!
        return b.distance(from: b.startIndex, to: range.lowerBound) / 2 + 1

    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

solution(88, 88553344) // 1
solution(55, 88553344) // 2
solution(33, 88553344) // 3
solution(44, 88553344) // 4
```

And even if you give one digit integer

```
solution(3, 88553344) // 3
```

Note: this solution will work only if your b will be the pair of 2 digits like `88553344`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you’re trying to think of that long number, `88553344`, as an array of values, `[88, 55, 33, 44]`. I.e., if you searched for `53`, I’m assuming you would not want to return any value. If so, I’d do that conversion to the array, and then search that:

```
public func solution(_ value1 : Int, _ value2 : Int) -> Int? {
    var array: [Int] = []
    var remainder = value2
    while remainder != 0 {
        array.insert(remainder % 100, at: 0)
        remainder /= 100
    }

    return array.firstIndex { $0 == value1 }
        .flatMap { $0 + 1 }
}
```

Or, if you didn’t want optionals and wanted to represent “not found” as, for example, zero, you could do:

```
public func solution(_ value1 : Int, _ value2 : Int) -> Int {
    var array: [Int] = []
    var remainder = value2
    while remainder != 0 {
        array.insert(remainder % 100, at: 0)
        remainder /= 100
    }

    return array.firstIndex { $0 == value1 }
        .flatMap { $0 + 1 } ?? 0
}
```

Note, that use of `0` as a magical sentinel value isn’t generally advised, but I’m inferring from your 1-based index that this might be desired. Use whatever value after the `nil`-coalescing operator, `??`, that you want. Personally, I’d stick with optionals.

---

Personally, since we live in a zero-based index world, I’d suggest that `88` should be `0`, `55` should be 1, etc.:

```
public func solution(_ value1 : Int, _ value2 : Int) -> Int? {
    var array: [Int] = []
    var remainder = value2
    while remainder != 0 {
        array.insert(remainder % 100, at: 0)
        remainder /= 100
    }

    return array.firstIndex { $0 == value1 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it this way :

```
public func solution(_ A : Int, _ B : Int) -> Int {

    guard A <= B, A > 0 else {
        return 0
    }

    let numberOfDigitsA = Int(log10(Double(A)) + 1)
    let tenthPowerA = Int(pow(10.0, Double(numberOfDigitsA)))
    let numberOfDigitsB = Int(log10(Double(B)) + 1)

    var b = B
    var result = 0

    while b > 0 {
        let remainder = b % tenthPowerA
        if remainder == A {
            result = numberOfDigitsB / numberOfDigitsA - result
            break
        }
        b = b / tenthPowerA
        result += 1
    }

    return result
}
```

This solution supposes that `B` is composed of groups of digits, with each group having the same number of digits as `A`. `0` is returned if no `B` doesn't *contain* the digits of `A`. The number *position* is 1-based.

And here are some test cases :

```
solution(55, 2233556677)    //3
solution(4, 9431)           //2
solution(123, 195000678123) //4
solution(111, 11)           //0
```